# Request.host returns `localhost` in Azure Functions using the worker model 'dotnet-isolated' and the ASP.NET Core integration

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-isolated

I am trying to convert an Azure Function app from the worker model `InProcess` to `Isolated Process`. For this I have decided to use the `aspnet-core-integration`, so my `HttpTrigger` takes in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest req` as an argument.

`req.host` is used to return a `RedirectUrl` for another function/endpoint running on the same domain, let's say `https://foobar.com/public/server-configuration` returns some json containing a `RedirectUrl` for `https://foobar.com/public/authenticated-server-configuration`.

Inside of the `HttpTrigger` for `https://foobar.com/public/server-configuration` I expected the `req.host` to be equal to `foobar.com`, but in this case I receive `localhost`, I get the feeling that it is somehow being rewritten locally.

This is just speculation but since my app is now being hosted in a different process, the host process for Azure functions will receive the request, startup a new process to handle the request, rewrite the request and sent it to the new process using `localhost`. Does anyone know what is going on? I was able to obtain the `req.host` using InProcess w/ the same infrastructure w.r.t proxies etc.

EDIT: maybe something like `X-Forwarded-Host` header would contain my real host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `X-Forwarded-Host` is indeed a way to get the original `req.host`

I'm changing `req.host` to `req.Headers["X-Forwarded-Host"]` but maybe w/ some slight modifications for making it more robust.